# how to copy a specific file from a android device on a root location

Tags: android, system

how to copy a specific file from a android device on a root location

I need to copy a file from a android device to usb but to do that I need root access.
Because the file is in the system file.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal and then type `sudo nautilus`

Yhis will open the file manager with root access